# Programmable bluetooth device with large range

Tags: wireless-networking, bluetooth

Apologies if this is not the appropriate forum to ask such a question.

I am looking to create a "bluetooth router" so to speak that can communicate with a few devices. The requirements are programmability (so I can make my own software) and range of the system.

Could one use a rasberry pi with an appropriate bluetooth module? What module would connect and give large (say over 25 meter) range?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to find transceivers with Class 1 Bluetooth radios.  Class 3 is range 1 meter, class 2 is 10 meters, and class 1 is 100 meters.  However, those use a lot of power (100 mW vs 2.5 mW for class 2 or 1 mW for class 1).  Also, keep in mind that Bluetooth uses the 2.4 GHz spectrum, which is extremely busy so you're likely to have much lower range than you'd otherwise obtain.

Personally, I think Bluetooth is the wrong technology.  Bluetooth is really intended for devices in the same room, and 25 m is out of that scope.

Comment: Thank you, further research is showing the BT is the wrong tech. Any idea what might be the right tech? I'm looking into RF transceivers with higher power outputs.

Comment: RF is the most direct equivalent, I think.  I'm more familiar with BT, however.  I had to research it several years back for wireless keyboards and mice in large auditoriums.  We ended up going with RF-based instead, but that's primarily because of the de-pairing issue that Bluetooth has.  For our largest rooms with front and rear hookups we actually had to use powered USB extenders.  Not wireless USB -- those sucked too -- actual USB KVM extenders using CAT 5 rated to 300m.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is LoRa, which is:

1. low power
2. large range (15km)
3. relatively easy to use